# How to download a portion of a video with youtube-dl OR something else?

Tags: video, youtube-dl

I'd like to be able to download a portion of a video only. For example, being able to specify a start and/or end time for downloading. So, when a user inputs a start and end time of a video, it should only download the portion of the clip within the time stamps. Would this be possible?

Comment: Don't think it's implemented in `youtube-dl` yet: https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl/issues/622. Google throws up many websites which provide this option.

Comment: Related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/230481/how-to-download-portion-of-video-with-youtube-dl-command

Answer (score 26):

There is indeed a [plethora](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-mTUmczVdik) of techniques available online to accomplish this. One fairly basic technique is the following *one liner* which works well enough on my system with a YouTube clip:

```
ffmpeg -i $(youtube-dl -f 18 --get-url https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZbZSe6N_BXs) \
-ss 00:00:10 -t 00:00:30 -c:v copy -c:a copy \
happy.mp4
```

The 2 sections which govern the clip start and end in this example are:

1. **-ss 00:00:10**: Placed *after* the input file this encodes and *discards* samples up until the 10 second mark. This is slower and less efficient than placing the seek options before the input file (*input seeking*) but works better in this example (in particular [when *copying* audio and video streams](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Seeking#Seekingwhiledoingacodeccopy))
2. **-t 00:00:30**: This specifies the duration of the encode, in this case 30 seconds only

I have tested this extensively with YouTube and all works well on my own system...

**References:**

- [youtube-dl Download Range](https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl/issues/622): Great discussion of the possibilities, some a little misguided :)
- [FFmpeg: Seeking](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Seeking) A solid outline of seeking, cutting and the correct time unit syntax

Answer (score 15):

Use the `--postprocessor-args` parameter to pass the audio/video output to `ffmpeg` to be edited (the processor). Apparently, `ffmpeg` is needed to be installed.

`--postprocessor-args` takes 3 arguments & values (this is just an example, check manual page of `ffmpeg` with `man ffmpeg` for more):

- `-ss HH:MM:SS`   : start time to take
- `-to HH:MM:SS`   : end time
- `-t HH:MM:SS`    : time length to take

Examples:

- Start encoding at 15 seconds and stop at 1 minutes 20 seconds:

  ```
  $ youtube-dl --postprocessor-args "-ss 0:0:15 -to 0:1:20" '[video_URL]'
  ```
- Start encoding at 15 seconds and take only the next 3 minutes 5 seconds:

  ```
  $ youtube-dl --postprocessor-args "-ss 0:0:15 -t 0:3:5" '[video_URL]'
  ```

**PS:** `youtube-dl` will download the entire media before processing it, and will remove it after.

Comment: That is very cool :)

Comment: This solution is totally awesome and thanx.
I wanted the ENG version of this 3:05:06 video of The History of The Eagles from the Arte site. 
So I had to run the -F command to see which as others dubbed FR or GER.
The video was downloaded in full but trimmed to my time specs
Very impressive!   

`youtube-dl -f HTTPS_SQ_2 --postprocessor-args "-ss 01:57:00 -t 03:05:06" url`

Answer (score 8):

The [plumber](https://snapcraft.io/plumber) tool allows you to do this easily. Install the application with:

```
snap install plumber
```

After installation, it will appear in your applications menu.

When you run the application, paste your desired youtube link in the box (highlighted in red in the screenshot below), or use the built-in youtube search feature, by clicking the youtube icon (highlighted in yellow).

Choose the start and end points. You can save your result as a video or gif.
[image: plumber application window]

Answer (score 7):

A nice alternative not shared here is [yt-dlp](https://github.com/yt-dlp/yt-dlp), a fork of `youtube-dl` which is far less held back by rate throttling. Its timing is accurate ("albeit slower") when given the `--force-keyframes-at-cuts` option:

```sh
yt-dlp --download-sections "*1:00:00-1:00:30" --force-keyframes-at-cuts [video_url]
```

I also passed the `--extract-audio --audio-format mp3` options and checked the true length of the resulting file with `ffprobe`:

```sh
ffprobe extracted_clip.mp3 2>&1 | grep Duration
  Duration: 00:00:30.02, start: 0.023021, bitrate: 68 kb/s
```

So the result is pretty accurate.

#### Speed

Result: **yt-dlp was 20x faster than youtube-dl**

for benchmarking, I ran the other answer's example below:

```sh
time ffmpeg -ss 00:00:37 -to 00:00:44 -i "$(youtube-dl -f best --get-url 'https://youtu.be/PVGeM40dABA')" -c:v copy -c:a copy coffee_sliding.mp4
```

This took 36 seconds on my machine.

Then I ran it the way I'm suggesting, using `yt-dlp`:

```sh
time yt-dlp -f best --download-sections "*0:00:37-0:00:44" --force-keyframes-at-cuts https://youtu.be/PVGeM40dABA
```

This took 1.8 seconds on my machine.

So by that simple benchmark it's 20 times faster!

I imagine the factor could change for different circumstances, but it's a promising signal.

#### Accuracy

Result: **yt-dlp was 76x more accurate than youtube-dl**

A faster method is not necessarily better if the result is worse in its accuracy.

I compared the extracted clips produced above against the expected duration (37s-44s = 7s duration).

The `youtube-dl` downloaded file was 8.52 seconds long (off by 1.52s).

```
ffprobe coffee_sliding.mp4 2>&1 | grep Duration
  Duration: 00:00:08.52, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 1702 kb/s
```

The `yt-dlp` downloaded file was 7.02 seconds long (off by 0.02s).

```
ffprobe coffee_sliding_ytdlp.mp4 2>&1 | grep Duration
  Duration: 00:00:07.02, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 1563 kb/s
```

Again, with all caveats of "just one test", this is 76x more accurate. What inaccuracy there is from yt-dlp, is pretty much negligible.

Comment: Wow, your `yt-dlp` solution is way better than [the `youtube-dl` ones](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/230481/37153)! Thank you! 

Answer (score 3):

I followed [andrew.46's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/990700/527764). However, you'd like to put `-ss` and `-t` or `-to` before `-i` for proper seeking. Otherwise, you'll download more than you want.
(`-t` specifies duration and `-to` specifies the output point; be careful as they are different)

In the manual of [ffmpeg](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Seeking), we are told to use `-t` or `-to` after `-i`.  However, based on my experience with ffmpeg, `-to` does not work after `-i`; it will be recognized as `-t`.

My example command is: (to download the cart sliding part of "Coffee Run")

```
ffmpeg -ss 00:00:37 -to 00:00:44 -i "$(youtube-dl -f best --get-url 'https://youtu.be/PVGeM40dABA')" -c:v copy -c:a copy coffee_sliding.mp4
```